# Linux Mint 18.1 64 not updating, mintupdate error

Tags: linux, linux-mint, updates, package-management, apt

Whenever I try to update Linux Mint 18.1, I get the following error from the Update Manager.

```
E: /var/cache/apt/archives/mintupdate_5.2.1.3_all.deb: subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
```

If I try to update from command line, I get the following:

```
    Preparing to unpack .../mintupdate_5.2.1.3_all.deb ...
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63
    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63
    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mintupdate_5.2.1.3_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mintupdate_5.2.1.3_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm kind of lost.

EDIT: Ok... I found some further info and it seems I messed up **royally**. That's what I get when I ask for versions on the terminal:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.3
$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.12
```

It's been long since I messed with this, and I no longer remember how I did this. I'm looking for how to revert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after quite some investigation, I've found a fix. IN the */usr/bin* dir, I found the link python pointing to */etc/alternatives*, which led me to the command `update-alternatives`.

By typing on terminal `update-alternatives --display python`, I get that `python` points to `python3.6` executable.

Use `sudo update-alternatives --set python` and enter the number presented as the desired option (python2.7, in this case).

Fixed.